# How to break trough an object frame in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, frame

Currently, I am working on a website that uses various frames to display content. One frame consists of a foldable menu, which needs more space than the actual frame is providing. Is it possible to break trough specific frame width without adjusting all pages? I don't want to use scrollbars and I am using z-indexes already.

As an example, I include two pages: index.html and includedpage.html. In this case, I want to see the text without adjusting index.html and without seeing scrollbars.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <object data="includedpage.html" width="100%" height="150"></object>

</body>
</html>
```

Includedpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        #content_need_to_displayed{
            margin-top: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content_need_to_displayed">
        Test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“I am working on a website that uses various frames to display content”_ – so far, so bad. Although you’re not really using frames here, but objects – but the usability drawbacks for both methods are about the same. You should really look for other ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*you need a bigger value for height ex :185*

```
<object data="includedpage.html" width="100%" height="185"></object>
```

margin-top + text(font-size )  + default user agent body margin ( top+bottom )= 150 + 18.5 + 16px (on Chrome)~=185px

or  you can use  percents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: green;
        }
        body,html{
          height:100%
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <object data="Includedpage.html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

</body>
</html>
```

js Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: green;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <object id="mypage" data="includedpage.html" width="100%"></object>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getDocHeight(doc) {
      doc = doc || document;
      // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
      var body = doc.body,
        html = doc.documentElement;
      var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
      return height;
    }

    function setIframeHeight(id) {
      var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
      var doc = ifrm.contentDocument ? ifrm.contentDocument :
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
      ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
      // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
      ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight(doc) + 4 + "px";
      ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    document.getElementById('mypage').onload = function() { // Adjust the Id accordingly
      setIframeHeight(this.id);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know this is possible, although this is not what I mean. I am searching for a way to retrieve the information on the included page without adjusting the height. Maybe this is not possible, but I am not sure.

Comment: I've update my answer with a js solution , you can't fix it only from CSS.